# Rename [scikit] tag to [scikit-learn]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

I'm proposing the renaming/synonymizing of [[scikit]](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scikit) tag to [scikit-learn].

Why?

- The tag has the form [scikit-learn] also in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scikit-learn) and [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scikit-learn)
- The tag in its current form can attract questions related to other [scikit-family libraries](https://github.com/search?q=scikit), even though the tag's current description states that it's specifically meant for questions related to [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/).

Also, the tag should be synonymized with [[sklearn]](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sklearn) tag.

The only reason that I can think of supporting the current form is brevity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds reasonable to me. I have implemented both of those mappings now.